# Cypress, read the data from API response

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, cypress

All of the example I found are with calling the API and defining method and URL. For example

```
  cy.server()

  cy.route({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'https://www.something.com', 
  }).as('get_jobs')

  cy.get('[data-cy="job-search-input"] button').click()

  cy.wait('@get_jobs').then((xhr) => {
     cy.log(xhr.response.body.data)
  })
```

What I want is just to select the button, press click and read the response that it gives me. I don't wanna define url and method  again, but use the one that is already used in the code and just check the response that it gives me after pressing the button.

How can I do that?

Comment: It's a little unclear what you're asking for here. Are you trying to use cypress to make a request to some API and get the response? The `cy.route` function is used to stub out a request for your application, so you're not actually making the request while testing.

Comment: my app is made that when I press the button I send some data and make API request. After I get response I save it to redux store. So I am not trying to stub anything. All the functionality is already implemented in the app. I just wanna test with cypress if I get response back after pressing the button and using that response for  next test.

Answer (score 5):

From the question and the comments above, it sounds like you're trying to do something like this:

1. set up your application
2. click a button (or do something else) to start a request to an API
3. capture the response from the API
4. use the response to test something else in your application (perhaps make sure some text changes on the page?)

While it is possible to write tests in this way, there is a problem with this: the response from the API may change depending on circumstances outside your control. For example, what happens if you're working on your project and the API happens to be down that day? Your code is going to break and it won't be due to a bug in your code. In fact, **you won't be testing your code at all (at least not the code you thought you were testing)**, because you won't be getting the response you want from the API.

This is why Cypress provides a way to stub the requests - to make sure that when your tests are running, you are getting the response you want from the API. If you want to write a test to see what happens when the API returns value A, you need to make sure the API doesn't return value B. Stubbing the requests allows you to make sure the application gets value A when you need it to.

So the examples you've seen probably do something like this:

1. set up your application
2. use `cy.route` to stub the API requests to return a known value
3. click the button - your app now makes a request and gets back that known value
4. test your application to make sure it does what you expect when it gets that known value.

If you have a range of different response values for which you want to test your app's behaviour, write a set of tests, one for each value.

Comment: That's true. But there are situation where I just wanna test if I get response back. For example I know I should get an array of items. It doesn't matter to me what are the items. I just wanna check if I get them in response when I press the button and if length of array is bigger then 0, because it always is and has to be.

Comment: So in effect what you're doing is testing the API. I would suggest that Cypress is not the correct tool for that.

Comment: Yes. But thats just one test of many. It's a shame to include a completly different testing tool just for few tests

Comment: Cypress is for end to end test as well, so checking response is part of end to end test!

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to read the response, you can use [`onReponse` in `cy.server`](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/server.html#The-following-options-are-merged-in-as-default-options-to):

```js
cy.server({
  onResponse(response) {
    // Log every response
    console.log("response", response);
    // Using the response URL from OP's question
    if (response.url.includes("https://www.something.com")) {
      // etc.
    }
  }
});
```